# SQL | Split Multiple Date Bands Into Individual Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How would I go about splitting multiple date bands into individual dates?

So from something like this:

```
DateStart   DateEnd
----------  ----------
2013-01-01  2013-01-03
2013-01-06  2013-01-08
```

To something like this:

```
Date
----------
2013-01-01
2013-01-02
2013-01-03
2013-01-06
2013-01-07
2013-01-08
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a CROSS join to your calendar table using

```
WHERE day_of_calendar BETWEEN DateStart and DateEnd
```

Or switch to Teradata where's a nice EXPAND ON :-)